# Classes in SQLFORM.factory web2py

Tags: web2py

I have created the following form

```
 search = SQLFORM.factory(Field('Search','string'))
```

and have following code for the html part:-

```
{{search.custom.begin}}
{{search.custom.submit["_class"] = "btn btn-primary"}}
<div class="form-group">{{=search.custom.widget.Search}}                                           
</div>                                                                                             
{{=search.custom.submit}}                                                                          
</form>
```

But in my browser, the submit button appears to be not working. While when I use {{=search}} instead, the button works flawlessly. Please suggest something. And i also need to give the form a class,which i am not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the view code should be:

```
{{=search.custom.begin}}
```

Note, your code is missing the `=`.

To add a class to the form, you can do:

```
search = SQLFORM.factory(Field('Search','string'),
                         _class='myclass')
```

You can also do:

```
search.add_class('myclass')
```

Note, the `add_class` method is equivalent to doing `search['_class'] = 'myclass'`, but it will also handle cases where you need to append to existing classes.

Comment: adding = to the code does not solve submit button problem.  Can you suggest something else.

Comment: I found the mistake, it was </form>.